# What is the path for the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM registry hive?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

If I open the **registry with the SYSTEM account** in Windows by using the *PSExec tool from SysInternals*:

```
psexec -i -s regedit
```

and I change an entry, for example, here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

... I presume that a corresponding `NTUSER.DAT` file will be modified.

**What is the path** to this `NTUSER.DAT` file?

Comment: I think it's c:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile.

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: Well, @ultrasawblade, in fact there is a `ntuser.dat` file there. I am trying to browse it from linux's tool `chntpw` to check what it is, but the key `\Software\Microsoft\` only contains a tree named `CTF`. There is nothing about the rest of the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` tree.

Comment: @Twisty, I am testing this matter with Windows XP SP3 and Windows 7. I think most Windows versions behave the same way.

Comment: Not true.  I believe Windows 7 stores the LocalSystem and NetworkService registry hives at 'C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\ntuser.dat' and C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\ntuser.dat' respectively.  These folders don't exist on XP.

Comment: Well, @Twisty, I have just made the change above (the `CurrentVerion\Run` key), and according to its modification date, none of these last two `ntuser.dat` files seem to be what we seek.

Comment: @Twisty: as it happent with the @ultrasawblade above suggestion, I have edited those `ntuser.dat` files, and they have only the `CTF` tree inside.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez - The path would be `C:\Users\<username>` , because `Run` key in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` implies that must be associated in that specific user profile.

Comment: @Ĭsααctիεβöss, the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` registry tree, when opened via `psexec -s` is a diferent one than if I open it via simple `regedit`, so I must suppose `<username>` here should be something like `SYSTEM`, and there is no `c:\Users\SYSTEM` folder in Windows computers.

Answer (score 5):

Contrary to common intuition, the `ntuser.dat` file in LocalSystem's user profile folder (`\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile`) is **not** the source of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` for applications running as SYSTEM. As far as I can tell, it's not actually used for anything, and it contains very little information.

In reality, the HKCU for applications running as SYSTEM is `.DEFAULT` under `HKEY_USERS`. (I'll address another common misconception: `.DEFAULT` [isn't the template for new user profiles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/03/02/1786493.aspx), `ntuser.dat` in `\Users\Default` is.) `.DEFAULT` is stored on disk in a file called `\Windows\System32\config\DEFAULT`. See [the MSDN article on Registry-backing files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724877(v=vs.85).aspx).

Also interesting: the list of the backing files for the various Registry hierarchies, including `.DEFAULT`, can be found in `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\hivelist`.

Comment: Is this expected to be valid for any version of Windows?

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez Essentially yes, from Windows NT and on, with appropriate substitution of `\WinNT` for `\Windows` and `\Documents and Settings` for `\Users` on Windows XP. [Further reading at TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc750583(en-us).aspx)